# Can i verify a list of xpaths at once?

Tags: selenium, automation, robotframework

I'm new using Robot Framework, so I created a Test Case to verify that a banch of elements exists on the target web page, so my question is instead of doing :

```
Page Should Contain Element    ${text_field1}
Page Should Contain Element    ${text_field2}
Page Should Contain Element    ${text_field3}
....
```

can I do a list with these xpaths and verify if this list exists on the web page  at once ?
is there any robotframework function to do that ? thanks

Comment: Not really, but you can loop over the list and call the kw over each member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we don't have a keyword for multiple checking elements in pages. But we can create that logic in an user keyword. See below a fully working example.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary    15    2
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER}        Chrome
@{elements}       xpath=//div[@id="error"]    id=searchInput    xpath=//button[@type="submit"]

*** Test Cases ***
Simple Test
    Open Browser    http://www.wikipedia.org    ${BROWSER}
    Comment    Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=searchInput    # search input field
    ${result}=    Page Should Contain Elements    ${elements}
    IF    not ${result}
        Fail    Page did not contained expected elements
    END
    Input Text    ${elements[0]}    Robot Framework
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${elements[1]}
    Click Button    ${elements[1]}
    Wait Until Page Contains    Robot Framework
    Capture Page Screenshot
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers

*** Keywords ***
Page Should Contain Elements
    [Arguments]    ${elements}
    @{results}=    Create List
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
        ${result}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Page Should Contain Element    ${element}
        IF    "${result[0]}" == "FAIL"
            Append To List    ${results}    ${element}
        END
    END
    ${ret}=    Evaluate    len(${results}) == 0
    Return From Keyword If    ${ret}    True
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{results}
        Log    Fail: Page should have contained element ${element} but it did not    WARN
    END
    Return From Keyword    False
```